# How do I debug a C++ application in vscode using the Visual Studio 2017 Toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I have read the [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md), and as far as I understand it I should be able to set the `type` in `launch.json` to `cppvsdbg` but this shows up greyed out, I'm guessing that indicates some kind of error? Then when I actually click debug I get this error:

```
Unable to start debugging. 
Launch options string provided by the project system is invalid. 
Unable to determine path to debugger. Please specify the "MIDebuggerPath" option.
```

[image: Unable to determine path to debugger]

However, when I actually go to set the MIDebuggerPath option to cdb.exe it tells me:

```
property MIDebuggerPath: is not allowed
```

[image]

Here are the extensions I'm using in case there's any possible conflict going on here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after some more digging I've at least figured out a work around. I was hitting this Debug button in the status bar at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

But if I switch to the debug mode by hitting the bug button on the left and then hit the green run arrow my debugger actually seems to work.

[image]

I still have no idea why these buttons do different things, or why the one on bottom doesn't work, but at least I can work around it for now. If anyone has any more insight on this I'd be happy to learn more.

Comment: I realize this is quite old, but regarding this discrepancy: The bottom toolbar "Debug" button fires up `cmake`'s build commands, whereas the latter debug button you described fires up your launch.json preferences. Just take a look at the output given when you hit the bottom debug button. Moreover, try to right click the bottom debug and hit "manage extension". It'll show cmake's extension details.